# How to select element by id within existing selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Given HTML:

```
<div id="div-a"></div>
<div id="div-b"></div>
<div id="div-c"></div>
```

And a previously-created jQuery selection:

```
var $divs = $("div");
```

How can I select a particular div in that selection by its id?
**Note:** the `$divs` selection has not yet been appended to the DOM, so I can't just select directly (e.g. `$("#div-b")`).

`find()` selects descendants of a selection, so this does not work:

```
$divs.find("#div-b");
```

`has()` / `:has()` selects elements that contain an element with the specified selector, so this does not work:

```
$divs.has("#div-b");
```

Comment: The other DIVs are not children, they're siblings.

Comment: @Diodeus yes, I know. That's why find(), has(), etc, don't work. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to reduce the set/.

```
var elem = $divs.filter("#div-b");
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var $subset = $divs.filter("#div-b");
```

Comment: geez people, you're answering faster than i can accept your answers, let alone test them.  F.J is the winner, with @epascarello a quick second.  thanks!

Comment: Actually I think @epascarello answered half a minute or so before me.

Comment: You're right! Lower number = more recent.  That's why SO requires you to wait 10 minutes to accept an answer I guess ;)

Comment: @ericsoco when the answers come in this fast, you can be sure that you could have figured this out by [reading the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: @Mathletics don't be snotty. I spent 15 minutes digging through the docs before I posted. jQuery has a big API and I didn't happen to find filter.

Comment: @ericsoco I meant it more as a warning for future readers; that said, the jQuery docs are broken down by section pretty clearly. There is even a [subsection on filtering](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/filtering/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only examine elements within a particular jQuery object that you've already created, you can use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method:

```
var $divs = $("div");
var item = $divs.filter("#div-a");
```

This will examine only the elements within the $divs jQuery object so see if any of them match the selector `"#div-a"` and will return to you a new jQuery object that contains only the matches (either zero or one object in this case).

Comment: Did you miss "The $divs selection has not yet been appended to the DOM, so I can't just select directly"

Comment: @epascarello - yep, I guess I missed that.  OK, then the second part of my answer would be the best choice in this case.  Edited my answer to remove the part about just using the id.